# gui in linux using gcc

Tags: c, linux, user-interface

hi every one i want ask that i have made a program and i have store a data in csv file. now i want a gui which includes buttons which upon pressing opens a a file and plot a graph.is there a way through which i can add gui in my program using gcc.and also i want to ask how can i make a moving graph just like ECG.

thank alot.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into using a toolkit like GTK+, if not i would suggest you check it out. GTK+ is written natively in C so i think it should work for you.

Comment: thanks alot sir . kindly tell me do i need to install it and can i open a file and display its data in the interface thanks

Answer (score 0):

Rephrasing your quesiton:

You have a C program that stores data in a csv file.  You wish to display this information as a graph but don't know how to build a GUI or graphical display.  Further, you want animation (it would be good if you linked to what "ECG" is) probably to display temporal aspects.

If I have this right, I suggest you learn the [GTK](http://www.gtk.org/) and [Cairo](http://www.cairographics.org/) libraries and use those to build your GUI.  Build GUI's is tedious and unrewarding work (to me), particularly in C.  I'd think hard about if you really want to bother making a GUI instead of doing something simple like calling out to [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) to build the graph as a file that the user can open, though this won't get you any animation.

Comment: thanks alot sir . kindly tell me do i need to install it and can i open a file and display its data in the interface thanks

Comment: you should clarify your post instead of posting the same comment multiple times. and what is ECG?

Comment: Indeed, in English the word `it` refers to the previously mentioned object, but you didn't mention any object.  I'm guessing you want to know how to install GTK and/or Cairo.  You should be able to find library and development packages for each in your Linux distribution's repository.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you switch your project to C++ and use [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products/) for your GUI.

Comment: but the project is almost completed it is the last part :(

Comment: try to compile it using g++ instead of gcc. It should work out of the box. and doing guis with qt is easy. http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/tutorials.html

Answer (score 0):

If gcc is not a requirement, then check out [SciPy](http://www.scipy.org/Getting_Started) or [Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/index.html).